# How to avoid repetation of .getJSON code in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of code in jQuery:

```
$(function() {         

      $.getJSON("json.js",function(result){          
      //operations            
      });
});
```

This `$.getJSON` function will be executed initially when page get loaded.
I want this function to be executed when a button is clicked without code repetition.
I have repeated the same code in a button click function now:

```
$("#btn_next").click(function(){

 $.getJSON("json.js",function(result){          
          //operations            
          });
    });
```

What would be the solution?

Comment: @How? Inside a jQuery block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just define and reuse a function

```
$(function() {         

  // reusable function
  var reloadData = function() {
    $.getJSON("json.js",function(result){          
      //operations            
    });
  };

  // button event
  $("#btn_next").click(function(event) {
    reloadData();
    event.preventDefault();
  });

  // init
  reloadData();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap it in a function, and call the function

```
$(function(){
 $.ajaxCall=(function() {         

      $.getJSON("json.js",function(result){          
         //operations 
      });

});


 $("#btn_next").click(function(event) {
    $.ajaxCall();
    event.preventDefault();
 });
 $.ajaxCall(); //call this whenever you want
});
```

Comment: You define `$.ajaxCall` then use `ajaxCall`. And you have syntax errors.

Comment: Not yet, you haven't closed the the document ready handler. Missing `)`.

Comment: Your contribution is much appreciated.